# What does boldness mean in the prompted hints in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

e.g. `.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer` is bold while `.equals` is not, what does boldnes mean?

[image]

Comment: I think the bold ones are members of your current class while the non-bold are from a super class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods directly on the class itself are in bold, and methods on super-classes are displayed in a lighter font. This list is usually ordered with the most frequently used methods at the top, if that information is available to the IDE.